# Can LAMBDA function, while doing aggregation, take condition from another column in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am looking for a way, if there exists a one, to perform an aggregatation on a `df` using only `lambda` approach, subject to a condition from another column. Here is a small microcosm of the problem.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,1,1,1,2,2],
                   'revenue':[40,55,75,80,35,60],
                   'month':['2012-01-01','2012-02-01','2012-01-01','2012-03-01','2012-02-01','2012-03-01']})
print(df)
   ID       month  revenue
0   1  2012-01-01       40
1   1  2012-02-01       55
2   1  2012-01-01       75
3   1  2012-03-01       80
4   2  2012-02-01       35
5   2  2012-03-01       60
```

If you need to have unique months for every `ID`, then the following code is good (this code is just for demonstration `'month':'nunique'` works here).

```
df = df.groupby(['ID']).agg({'month':lambda x:x.nunique()}).reset_index()
print(df)
   ID  month
0   1      3
1   2      2
```

But, I need to count unique `months` when revenue was greater than 50 by taking two variables (revenue & month) in `lambda` something like `lambda x,y: ...` .

I could have done it like `df[df['revenue'] > 50].groupby.(....)`, but there are many other columns in the `agg()` where this condition is not needed. So, does there exist an approach where `lambda` could take 2 variables simultaneously??

**Expected output:**

```
   ID  month
0   1      3
1   2      1
```

Comment: Can you add expected output?

Comment: Addeded now for clarity

Comment: You can use `groupby(...).apply(...)` which will give you the chunked dataframe to do whatever you want in your lambda or function. `agg` will give you only 1 column

Comment: with `apply()` it works .... I was just wondering if lambda accomodates two variables

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it is possible not easy/ performance way, because [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) processing each column separately:

**Dont use it, because extremly slow if large df or many groups.**

```
def f(x):
   a = df.loc[x.index]
   return a.loc[a['revenue'] > 50, 'month'].nunique()


df1 = df.groupby(['ID']).agg({'month':f}).reset_index()
print(df1)
   ID  month
0   1      3
1   2      1
```

So one possible solution is filter before or using [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html).

Comment: I can't filter, as there are other columns to aggregate. Thank you for clarifying that its not possible.

Comment: @cph_sto - Possible, but... added to answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot jezrael. Can't accept it as an answer for obvious reasons, but have upvoted it already.